# Future и получение данных по мере их выполнения

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, execute, future

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.
Шлю запрос в базюки и получаю время выполнения запроса.

Ниже представлен метод в контроллере, в котором в теле запроса я передаю какой-то запрос. Создаю пул из 3 потоков, в executor-е вызываю 3 метода, которые отправляют этот запрос на 3 разные базюки, и оборачиваю это все в  `Future<Map<String, Object>>`
Потом при помощи future.get я жду пока не получу результат из всех 3 потоков и возвращаю его в качестве map.

Проверяю через **Postman**: когда отправляю запрос, идет время ожидание запроса в течении допустим 3 секунд и я получаю результат.

Вопрос поставлен следующим образом: 
1) Параллельно одновременно отправить запрос на 3 базы
2) Необходимо запретить повторно отправлять запрос пока не будет получен результат со всех 3 потоков, а не одного например (первый поток освободился, 2-ой и 3-ий занят и мы можем на первый поток еще раз выполнить наш запрос в базу)

```
@PostMapping(value = "/select/")
public Map<String, Object> callSelectQuery(@RequestBody SelectQuery query) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException, ExecutionException {

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    Future<Map<String, Object>> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        Map<String, Object> mapMySql = mySqlService.select(query);
        Map<String, Object> mapPostgreSQL = postgreSqlService.select(query);
        Map<String, Object> mapH2DB = h2Service.select(query);
        list.add(mapMySql);
        list.add(mapPostgreSQL);
        list.add(mapH2DB);
        return list;
    });

    System.out.println("Future is done? " + future.isDone());

    Map<String, Object> result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("Future is done? " + future.isDone());
    System.out.println("result: " + result);

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    return result;
}
```

один из 3-ех методов запроса в базу (получаю время выполнения):

```
public Map<String, Object> select(SelectQuery query) {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();

    try {
        final Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        mysqlTemplate.queryForList(String.valueOf(query));
        sw.stop();
        long executionTime = sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        map.put("MySQL execution time: ", executionTime + " ms");
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        logger.error("Error select data: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Подскажите, верно ли написан данный функционал ?
Действительно ли во время выполнения 3 методов в базу я жду их выполнения и только тогда, когда будут готовы все 3 запроса, я получу результат Future и я не могу отправить запрос повторно ?

Спасибо!

---

Дополнение:
Вариант 2:

Использовал CompletableFuture на каждый поток.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/select/")
public  List<Map<String, Object>>  callSelectQuery(@RequestBody SelectQuery query) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException, ExecutionException {

    List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    Future<List<CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>>>> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>> futureMySql = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> mySqlService.select(query));
        CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>> futurePostgreSql = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> mySqlService.select(query));
        CompletableFuture<Map<String, Object>> futureH2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> mySqlService.select(query));

        futuresList.add(futureMySql);
        futuresList.add(futurePostgreSql);
        futuresList.add(futureH2);

        return futuresList;
    });

    List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = futuresList.parallelStream()
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return resultList;
}
```

Не уверен что верно. В результате постманом выводит одинаковые значения для трех баз:

```
[
    {
        "MySQL execution time: ": "225 ms"
    },
    {
        "MySQL execution time: ": "225 ms"
    },
    {
        "MySQL execution time: ": "225 ms"
    }
]
```

Comment: почему вы в вашей лямде возвращаете только mapPostgreSQL?

Comment: @Dred да, это опечатка. Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Как я вижу это, вам нужно сделать 3 Executors, по 1 для каждой базы, например, описано [тут](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-fixed-size-thread-pool-executor-example/) После этого, вы отправляете запрос. Размер пула, пусть будет 1. В таком случае, если у вас будет 1 запрос выполняться дольше 3 секунд, вы вручную его прервете еще через 5 секунд (судя по вашему коду). А, если запрос выполнится, то из пула возьмется новый поток для вашей базы. Вопрос только в том, как вы хотите разделять ваши запросы по базам...

Comment: @Dred ну я хочу чтобы когда я отправил запрос больше никто не смог отправить его повторно ни в первую, ни во вторую, ни в третью базу, пока мне не вернутся все три потока с трех баз полностью. Главный критерий, это чтобы эти 3 запроса отправлялись параллельно (одновременно), когда я отправляю запрос по url:  http://localhost:8080/select

Comment: А чего бы не завернуть каждый вызов `select` в отдельный `CompletableFuture`, а потом получить из них комбинированную футуру и дождаться её завершения?

Comment: А ещё лучше не дожидаться в методе контроллера, а переложить эту задачу на Spring, вернув из метода `CompletableFuture` или `DeferredResult`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я прочитал про DeferredResult, где настоятельно рекомендуют использовать его чтобы предотвратить блокировку. Мне наоборот надо сделать блокировку до тех пор, пока я не получу все 3 результат из моего пула потоков. Как только я получу все 3, тогда можем отправить запрос еще раз. Но если выполнилось 2, а 3-ий еще нет, чтобы я не мог повторно отправить запрос в свободный пул.

Comment: @ks2017 если нужно исключить повторные запросы к БД при повторных http-запросах, то этот код нужно вынести в сервисный слой и регулировать доступ в нём. Что кстати не исключает использования `CompletableFuture` как для запросов к БД, так и в ответе контроллера.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил в пост Дополнение. не уверен что правильно понял, но мне кажется идея такая ? Или я снова ошибаюсь ? Буду очень благодарен вам, если поможете. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за комментарии.
Переписал логику использую Stream API, на основной метод поставил synchronized и использовал обычный Future.